# How to perform a wildcard without If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have two `select` option, lets say :

```
<select id="main">
    <option value="1">category 1</option>
    <option value="2">category 2</option>
    ........
</select>

<select id="sub">
    <option value="1-1">sub 1</option>
    <option value="1-2">sub 2</option>
    <option value="2-3">sub 3</option>
    <option value="2-4">sub 4</option>
    ........
</select>
```

whenever `category 1` is selected, all option from `sub select` should be disabled, **except** those with value start with `1`, which is `sub 1` and `sub 2`

I have this code so far:

```
$('#main').on('change', function() {        
    var opt=this.value.trim();          
    $("#sub > option").attr("disabled", "disabled");                    
    $("#sub > option[value=opt+'%']").removeAttr("disabled");   
                                ^ I just can't figure how to perform a wild card here
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `^=` attribute match. Change

```
$("#sub > option[value=opt+'%']")
```

to

```
$('#sub > option[value^="' + opt + '"]')
```

This will check if the `value` attribute **starts with** the string in `opt`. Reference: [Attribute selectors - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: perfect! I've seen this before, but just can't recall it. thank you!